# Public transport planning in Fez, Morocco

Tags: public-transport, planning, morocco

Is there a resource that plans routes, or even a simple map with schedules of public transport in Fez?

I have looked it up, and I was unable to find it.
Rome to Rio, does this to a certain extent but fails in providing accurate schedules.
Google maps does not have information for Fez.
I also tried Moovit. It contains all major cities in Morocco except for Fez.

**Are there any online resources with public transport schedules for Fez, Morocco?**

Comment: Even what seems to be the [official page](http://www.cbtransport.online/fes/%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ae%d8%b7%d9%88%d8%b7-3/) of the Fes bus service doesn't offer much information. There is a list showing which bus goes where, but that's about it.